# Orthogonal group is a regular submanifold of $GL(n,\Bbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I want to show that $O(n)$ is a regular submanifold of $GL(n,\Bbb R)$. I think that I can use constant rank theorem but how? I am putting the picture that what I did. Please help me I want to learn.

[image]

Comment: A good question @Busem3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the function $f:A\mapsto A^tA$ defined on the vector space $V=M_n(\mathbb R)$ of $n\times n$ matrices.

Let $A_0\in O(n,\mathbb R)$.

Let $B\in V$ and let us compute the derivative of $f$ at $A_0$ in the direction of $B$, namely, $$D_{A_0}f(B):=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(A_0+hB)-f(A_0)}{h}.$$ Using the definition of $f$, we have 
\begin{align}\frac{f(A_0+hB)-f(A_0)}{h}&=\frac{(A_0+hB)^t(A_0+hB)-A_0^tA}{h}\\
&=\frac{A_0^tA_0+h(B^tA_0+A_0^tB)+h^2B^tB-A_0^tA_0}{h}\\
&=B^tA_0+A_0^tB+hB^tB,
\end{align}
so that obviously the limit above is 
  $$D_{A_0}f(B)=B^tA_0+A_0^tB.$$
Can you compute the rank of the differential $D_{A_0}f:V\to V$ that we have just computed?

Notice that $D_{Id}f(A^tB)=D_Af(B)$. As long as $A$ is invertible, this implies that the maps $D_{Id}f$ and $D_Af$ have the same rank, so it is enough to compute the rank of $D_{Id}$.

Comment: You can also consider $f$ as mapping into the vector space of symmetric matrices.  Then you can show very explicitly that $D_{A_0} f$ is surjective.

Comment: @EricO.Korman, it is exactly the same computation.

Comment: Thanks your helping :) @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: Range of Df(A0) should be space of all symmetric matrices not V @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: Could you please explain why $A$ being invertible ensures that $D_{A} f$ and $D_{Id} f$ have the same rank?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez , Can you help me in understanding what definition of the differential map you are using and what is the concept behind it? Because I just cannot remember something without actually understanding it.

Comment: What I understand is, given a map $f:M\to N$, the differential $DF_p:T_pM \to T_qN$ is the differential map. Now the differentials are nothing but special functions $\omega:C^\infty(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying some properties. Now let us focus on the differential map $ DF_p:T_pM \to T_qN$, for a given $\omega:C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb{R}$, we need to define a map $\omega': C^\infty(N) \to \mathbb{R}$ using $\omega$. But how are we going to compute it explicitly using curves?