# Differential of a smooth map computation

Tags: differential-topology, topological-groups

I wanted to compute the differential of the map $f:M_n(\mathbb{R})\to S_n(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $f(A)=AA^T$ but how can I compute it explicitly?

it has been done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369530/orthogonal-group-is-a-regular-submanifold-of-gln-bbb-r)  but I am not sure how and why it is being done that way.

What I understand is, given a map $F:M\to N$, the differential $DF_p:T_pM \to T_qN$ is the differential map. Now the differentials are nothing but special functions $\omega:C^\infty(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying some properties. Now let us focus on the differential map $ DF_p:T_pM \to T_qN$, for a given $\omega:C^\infty(M) \to \mathbb{R}$, we need to define a map $\omega': C^\infty(N) \to \mathbb{R}$ using $\omega$. But how are we going to compute it explicitly using curves?

I also know that any such differential $\omega$ is given by a smooth curve
$\gamma_\omega:I \to M$ as follows

$$\omega(g)=\frac{d( g \circ \gamma_\omega)}{dt}$$ but I am not able to understand how to compute the differentials

Comment: The answer that you linked derives the derivative of $f$ at any point and in any direction. Do you understand that part?

Comment: yeah, but why are we doing that. I am not quite sure how directional deriviatives help?

Comment: @Snared, how does it gives me a map from $T_p M \to T_q N$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986070/the-relationship-between-the-differential-and-the-directional-derivative-of-a-fu Leafing through this while I think about it

Comment: More precisely there in the linked post, $DF_{A_0}$ is the differential of the map $F$ and thus $B$ is an element of $T_{A_0}M$? but I cannot understand how $B$ is an element of T_{A_0}M? An element of tangent space is a map from $C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ and I cannot see how a matrix $B$ will define a function $C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: You can define $df_p$ using the directional derivatives in the natural way. Reicz representation theorem is not needed since we are dealing with finite dimensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141382/discussion-between-permutation-matrix-and-snared).

Answer (score 2):

For any manifold $M$, you can consider the tangent space at a point $p\in M$ as the set of curves through that point modulo the equivalence relation $\gamma_1\sim\gamma_2 \iff \gamma_1(0)=p =\gamma_2(0)\  \text{and}\ \gamma_1'(p)=\gamma_2'(p)$. In this setting, $DF_p(v)$ for $v\in T_pM$ is computed as follows:

1. Pick a curve $\gamma\in M$ such that $\gamma'(0)=v\in T_pM$.
2. Compute
   $$ DF_p(v)=\frac{d}{dt}\big(F\circ \gamma\big)\big\vert_{\ t=0} $$

If you think about it for a second, you will see that this is nothing but computing the velocity of the image of $\gamma$ under $F$ at $F(p)$. In some sense, you are pushing forward $v$ via $\gamma$.

As for your example, observe that $M_n(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and $S_n(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$. Since they are Euclidean, we can identify them with their tangent spaces, i.e. $T_pM_n(\mathbb{R})\cong M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $T_{F(p)}S_n(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$. Hence the differential is a map of the following form
$$DF_p: M_n(\mathbb{R})\longrightarrow S_n(\mathbb{R})$$
Now for $v\in T_pM_n(\mathbb{R})$, which we know is just an $n\times n$ matrix, we can simply pick the curve
$$\gamma(t) = p + tv$$
It is clear that $\gamma$ satisfies $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$. Now by step $(2)$ above, we have
\begin{align}
DF_p(v) &= \frac{d}{dt}\big(F\circ \gamma\big)\big\vert_{\ t=0} = \frac{d}{dt}\big(F(p+tv)\big)\big\vert_{\ t=0} = \frac{d}{dt}\big((p+tv)(p+tv)^T\big)\big\vert_{\ t=0} \\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\big((p+tv)(p^T+tv^T)\big)\big\vert_{\ t=0} = \frac{d}{dt}\big(pp^T+tpv^T+tvp^T+t^2vv^T\big)\big\vert_{\ t=0} \\
&= pv^T+vp^T
\end{align}
as promised.

Answer (score 0):

We have

\begin{align}
f(A+H) &= (A+H)(A+H)^T = (A+H)(A^T+H^T)\\[1.5ex]
&= AA^T+AH^T+HA^T+HH^T\\[1.5ex]
&= f(A) + AH^T+HA^T+HH^T
\end{align}

so

$$ df(A)(H) = AH^T+HA^T $$

being $\,H\longmapsto AH^T+HA^T\,$ a linear continuous function $M_n(\mathbb R)\longrightarrow S_n(\mathbb R)$, $\,$and $\,HH^T = o(H)$.

Note that the directional derivative of $f$ at $A$ along $H$ is given by

$$ D_Hf(A) = df(A)(H).$$

Answer (score -1):

The question you linked computed the directional derivative call it $f^{\text{directional derivative}}(p,v)$ of $f$ at any point $p$ and in any direction $v$, as you have agreed in the comments. Now, to define $df_p$, we can simply evaluate

$$df_p(v) = f^{\text{directional derivative}}(p,v)$$

So, in this case, for your $f$,

$$df_p(v) = v^tp+p^tv $$

due to the logic written in the answer you have linked. Basically your question amounts to how *exactly* the derivative and directional derivatives are linked in finite dimensions, since you are using an answer that gives the directional derivatives for your $f$.

Comment: so $df_p$ is a map from tangent space of $M_n$ to Tangent space of $S_n$ but how they are actually a derivation?

Comment: can you confirm if $v$ and $pv^t+vp^t$ are elements of tangent spaces?